# `tf.data.Dataset.map` with variable dependencies

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm looking to train a model with preprocessing dependent (non-differentiably) on model parameters. My current solution is to use `tf.compat.v1.data.make_initializable_iterator` and re-initialize each epoch, but this has the following issues:

- updates are only applied once each epoch. I'm alright with using slightly out-dated values (a few passes through the network) but I'd rather a faster update frequency than this which doesn't reset the batching process;
- I'd rather do things the 2.0 way, and as far as I can tell 2.0 has not `make_initializable_iterator`; and
- I'd like a way that's eager-mode compatible.

The following demonstrates the issue in eager mode.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

n = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.range(n),))

# create a simple keras model to implement the map function
vi = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32)
xi = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32)
out = tf.keras.layers.Add()([xi, vi])
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[xi, vi], outputs=out)

# create a variable-dependant tensor for input
v = tf.Variable(0., dtype=tf.float32)*2


def map_fn(x):
    return model([tf.cast(x, tf.float32), v2])


dataset = dataset.map(map_fn)
for d in dataset:
    print(d.numpy())  # 0, 1, 2, 3, ... as expected
v.assign(100.)
for d in dataset:
    print(d.numpy())  # 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., expected 200, 201, 202, ...
```